# Chromes security stops me from sending emails, would android also stop it?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-chrome, email

I'm making a Cordova app. I have an email sending function, when i test my app in chrome i get the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I have looked through out stack overflow and havent been able to find a solution. Nothing ive seen has worked. Some people say this problem is specific to chrome and other browsers. If its only browsers that are the problem when i run my app on android everything should be fine and the email should send, right? Heres the code if you wanted to see:

```
   var message = localStorage.getItem("Message");
var key = "xxthisisakeyxx";
var message_name = "send_message";
var data = {};
data.value1 = message;
data.value2 = localStorage.getItem("AdminsEmail");
var url = "https://example.com/trigger/" + message_name + "/with/key/" + key;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    console.log("Message Sent");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
    }
}
}

xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:8000");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
xmlhttp.responseType = 'json';
xmlhttp.send(new FormData(data));
```

Thank you

Comment: @JaromandaX ...thanks but is this a problem only with chrome? will this problem still occur if its an app on a phone?

Comment: i meant only with browsers*, not just chrome. Would this problem occur on android?

Comment: no, not the browsers on android. When i build and run this as an app on android would it have the same problem?

Comment: oh, sorry, totally misunderstood the question (I'll remove my comments regarding CORS) - sorry, I don't know enough about native android apps to help

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be the access-control on the server side script.

Example: If you are posting the data to a php script you may need to include this line at the top of the .php file:

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

This can be unsafe but if you are posting the data from inside a Cordova app it may be hard to specify an exact origin.